# Solving this inhomogenous system of two linear recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence-relations, matrix-equations

I have this system of recurrence relations (where $\forall n\in\Bbb N: b^{(n)}, c^{(n)}\in\Bbb R$):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}b^{(n+1)}\\c^{(n+1)}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\over2^{n+1}\\0\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}\frac34 & \frac14 \\ \frac14 & \frac34\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}b^{(n)} \\ c^{(n)}\end{pmatrix}.
$$

How can I find an explicit formula for all the $b^{(n)}, c^{(n)}$?

My question stems from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3238042/matrix-with-limit). The latter question is trivial to solve if my question from above is answered.

I thought about using some fixed point Theorem, but the calculations seem to get messy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint.

Making

$$
M=\frac 14\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right) = V^{\dagger}\cdot\Lambda\cdot V,\ \ U_n=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 b_n \\
 c_n \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

with

$$
V = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and

$$
\Lambda = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac 12 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Then

$$
U_{n+1}=V^{\dagger}\cdot \Lambda\cdot V\cdot U_n + \delta_n
$$

This is a linear recurrence with solution

$$
U_n = U_n^h+U_n^p\\
U_{n+1}^h - M\cdot U_n^h = 0\\
U_{n+1}^p - M\cdot U_n^p =\delta_n
$$

then

$$
U_n^h = V^{\dagger}\cdot\Lambda^n\cdot V\cdot C_0
$$

now calling $U_n^p = V^{\dagger}\cdot \Lambda\cdot V\cdot C_n$ and substituting we have

$$
V^{\dagger}\cdot\Lambda^{n+1}\cdot VC_{n+1}=V^{\dagger}\cdot\Lambda^{n+1}\cdot VC_n +\delta_n
$$

giving

$$
C_{n+1}-C_n  = V\Lambda^{-(n+1)}\cdot V^{\dagger}\cdot \delta_n = \frac 14\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2+2^{-n} \\
-2+2^{-n} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

etc.

and finally

$$
U_n = V^{\dagger}\cdot\Lambda^n\cdot V\cdot\left(C_0+C_n\right)
$$

NOTE

According to @G Cab calling $W = V\cdot U$ and $\rho = V\cdot\delta_n$ we can write also

$$
W_{n+1} = \Lambda\cdot W_n + \rho_n
$$

which is easier to handle.

Comment: better $(VU)_{n+1} = \Lambda (VU)_{n}+(V \delta_n)$

Comment: @GCab Yes. I agree. Cleaner.

Comment: Under which topic/subject could I learn more about this please?

Comment: @NoChance the theme of linear difference equations feeds on linear algebra. In the non-linear world, each case is an independent universe. There is a book that is old but available on the web and has very illustrative chapters on the equations of differences. A TREATISE ON THE CALCULUS OF FINITE DIFFERENCES. George Boole.


http://www.archive.org/details/cu31924031240934

Comment: @Cesareo, thank you kindly sir. Such a nice help.